# Finding Radius of curvature of given polar curve in python

Tags: python, sympy

We are given with a curve like - l/r = 1+e*cos(theta) . And we have find radius of curvature at any given point (r,theta)in polar form using formula

```py
ROC = (r**2 + (r1)**2) / (r**2 - (r1)**2 - (r * r2)) .
```

My try -

```py
from sympy import *
#from math import *
#import numpy as np

theta ,r ,l ,e= symbols('theta r l e')

r = l/(1+e*cos(theta))

dybydx = diff(r,theta)
dybydx_value = ((dybydx.subs(r,r)).subs(theta,theta))

dsqybydxsq = diff(r,theta)
dsqybydxsq_value = ((dsqybydxsq.subs(r,r)).subs(theta,theta))

roc = simplify((((r)**2 + (dybydx_value)**2)**(3/2))/((r)**2 + 2 * (dybydx_value)**2 - (r * dsqybydxsq_value)))

pprint(simplify(roc))
```

> Expected Output -
> (2 * (r)**(3/2))/root(a)

> My Input  -
> [image: My output]

Comment: And what's the issue?

Comment: output is coming wrong

Comment: check your output line by line; right now dybydx is the same as dsqybydxsq and your subs don't do anything when the old and new patterns are the same, `eq.subs(x,x)` will always just be `eq`.